# Set the option in a select of objects when the options are fetched from an API in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm doing a web application in Angular 8. I use Reactive Forms and I have a select that I fill fetching an API. The options that I get from the API are an array of objects like this:

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'Number one', requireDocumentNumber: true},
   {id: 2, name: 'Number two', requireDocumentNumber: true},
   {id: 3, name: 'Number three', requireDocumentNumber: false},
]
```

I'm using `ngValue` in the select to store the whole object inside the formControl.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="reasonSelect">Select an option</label>
               <select class="form-control"
                    formControlName="reason"
                    id="reasonSelect">
                  <option *ngFor="let r of reasonList" [ngValue]="r">
                     {{r.name}}
                  </option>
                 </select>
           </div>
       </form>
```

I'm using `setValue` to set the desired object into the formControl, but, the option is not selected in the form.

```
reasonList: IReason[] = [];
  form: FormGroup;
  objectToAssign = {
    id: 2, 
    name: 'Number two', 
    requireDocumentNumber: true
    };

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      reason: [null, Validators.required],
    });

    // async reasons
    of(this.getReasons())
    .delay(2000)
    .subscribe(r => {
      this.reasonList = r;
      // setValue
      this.form.get('reason').setValue(this.objectToAssign);
    });
  }

  getReasons() {
    return [
      {id: 1, name: 'Number one', requireDocumentNumber: true},
      {id: 2, name: 'Number two', requireDocumentNumber: true},
      {id: 3, name: 'Number three', requireDocumentNumber: false},
    ];
  }
```

The object is inside of the formControl, but, it's not selected in the form.

[image]

I have created a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzxixn

My goal is to set the desired option in the form to show the name while keeping the entire object inside the formControl.

Answer (score 0):

You must change `this.form.get('reason').setValue(this.objectToAssign);` to `this.form.get('reason').setValue(this.reasonList[1]);` and it will be selected on the select after fetching the options from your API.

Comment: I don't get it. Why? That means that I need to find the index of my desired option in the fetched list to assign it to the formControl? I don't see the logic here if I'm assigning the same object as I showed in the example. What's the difference?

Comment: For some reason it worked in the demo that I provided, but it is not working in my app with a real http request. The select is still empty. I hope you can give me an extra hand.

Comment: Sorry. If this is not working try using and ngModel in your select. When you fetch the information from your API you can assign the value of the ngModel `this.selectedReason = this.reasonList[1];`. Here you have a demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktpcl).

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help. For some reason that solution is only working in the demo, not with real data coming from the API. A solution that has worked is using the directive `compareWith` inside the `select` tag to do the comparison internally by the id.

Comment: Long time ago ... maybe you still read my comment and could provide an updated StackBlitz with the working "compareWith" approach. I tried to use the same ("compareWith") approach but failed.